# Preciso pegar a URL atual e saber se após index.php tem "?" ou "&"

Tags: url

A parte inicial para pegar a URL eu ja fiz usando este codigo:

```
//URL ATUAL
$url_atual = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
echo $url_atual;
```

.....
Se eu estiver na url
http://localhost/index.php me retorna: index.php

se eu estiver na url 
http://localhost/index.php?module=guia me retorna: index.php?module=guia

Porém eu preciso saber como saber se após o index.php esta usando algum "?" como este exemplo: index.php?module=guia.....

pois preciso criar um link

se for só index.php acrescenta:
?lang=1">

resultado index.php?lang=1

ou

se for index.php?module=guia
&lang=1">

resultado index.php?module=guia&lang=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Não seria mais simples usar `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` que é feita para exatamente isto?**

Se entendi quer adicionar aos links existentes, deve ficar assim:

```
$querystring = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//Adiciona o ? se a querystring não for vazia
if ($querystring != '') {
     $querystring = '?' . $querystring;
}

echo '<a href="index.php', $querystring,'">';
echo '<a href="index.php', $querystring,'&foo=bar">';
```

Se quiser editar os valores da query string basta usar a função `http_build_query()` com `$_GET`, supondo que você tenha uma URL assim:

```
 index.php?foo=bar&baz=2
```

E queira trocar o valor de `baz=` e gerar o link então faça isto:

```
$querystring = '';

//Array vazias não passa no IF, não é necessário `if (!empty())`
if ($_GET) {
    //Copia o GET
    $manipula = $_GET;

    $manipula['baz'] = 10; //Trocou o valor para 10

    $querystring = '?' . http_build_query($manipula, '', '&amp;'); // O uso de `&amp;` é para HTML, mas na URL ele será tratado como & apenas
}

echo '<a href="index.php', $querystring,'">';
```

Isto irá gerar um link assim:

```
index.php?foo=bar&baz=10
```

Comment: Usei o seu segundo exemplo, deu certo, pois além de adicionar o que eu queria em um link existente.. ele não repete
antes quando eu selecionava um idioma de portugues para ingles com o link ja existente
EX: index.php?module=registro&lang=pt
ele repetia: index.php?module=registro&lang=pt&lang=en
agora com essa manipulação, não existe mais esse problema, Obrigado!!

Comment: https://www.gbrwc.com <---- ja esta funcionando neste site =)

Answer (score 0):

> Pegar a parte inicial com

```
$url_atual = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
```

> pode trazer resultados inesperados, veja por exemplo, caso a url seja

```
http://dominio.com/diretorio3/index.php?module=guia
```

> $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] vai ser

```
diretorio3/index.php?module=guia
```

> e após o replace o resultado será

```
diretorio3index.php?param=module=guia
```

### Sugestão:

```
$url_atual = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$result = (parse_url($url_atual , PHP_URL_QUERY));

if ($result !== null) {
    echo $url_atual."&lang=1";
} else {
    echo $url_atual."?lang=1";
}
```

[**parse_url**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php)— Interpreta uma URL e retorna os seus componentes

**PHP_URL_QUERY**  após a interrogação `?`

[**exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/aMQSnh)

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz um código aqui que resolveu o problema

`//URL ATUAL
$url = str_replace("/", "", $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
if ($url == '') {
    $url_atual = "index.php";
} else { $url_atual = $url; }`

echo $url_atual; if ($url_atual != "index.php") { echo "&lang=en"; } else { echo "?lang=en"; }